# Which is a better way of reusing an array: instantiating an array, releasing it, and reinstantiating, or just clearing the array's objects?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

For a quiz app, I have a class that stores data in arrays that are related to a specific question. When the user moves on to the next question, I need empty data arrays.

Is it better if I did something like

```
[class release]; //assume that I properly release the arrays and their objects

[class alloc] init];
```

or

`[arrays removeAllObjects];`

or an alternate approach not mentioned?

I feel that my code would be simpler if I use the first solution, but I'm worried that I would be taking up too much memory, since the process would be done multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the simple solution. After you encounter (measure!) problems start to optimize, not before.

There's really no point in wondering what is more efficient if you don't see any inefficiency.